# Using a rotation vector in earlier Android systems

Tags: java, android

Hey, for an application I am writing I need to use the data which is given in [Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html#values). The bad news are that I program, among others, to my G1 device, which runs Android 1.6, i.e. API Level 4, and not 9 as needed. Nevertheless, I am pretty positive that my phone does have a sort of gyroscope, which means it should be possible for me to get the exact orientation of the phone. So, the question is, how do I do it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that the G1 has a gyroscope - [it just has the basic accelerometers](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3619/do-any-phones-other-than-the-samsung-s-have-gyroscope-capabilities).  [Here](http://blog.radioactiveyak.com/2011/01/how-to-use-gyroscope-api-and-remain.html)'s an interesting post about how to program to use accelerometers when they are available and not crash when they aren't.

[Update]
If your phone has a gyroscope, you will require Android 2.3 (and above) on the phone to get access to it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought that too, especially when trying to run the gyroscope causes it to force close, but then I saw http://twitter.com/#!/steveplunkett/status/7793317253 and  http://forum.xda-developers.com/archive/index.php/t-436592.html, so I don't know what to think any more...

Comment: Based off of the android.stackexchange post in my message, I think that the "g-sensors" are "gravity-sensors" rather than "gyroscopic-sensors".  I could definitely be wrong, however.  That said, I think you'd have to get Gingerbread onto the phone to get access to the Gyroscope API.

Comment: Well, I could say for sure that there are gravity sensors in my phone. I don't know what Gingerbread is, but I can access the Gyroscope API (I mean, I can write "TYPE_GYROSCOPE" without getting a compilation error). I wouldn't mind having a less accurate sensor, but I do need to know the exact 3D orientation (gravity sensor don't give away the whole orientation)... Thanks.

Comment: Gingerbread is Android 2.3 - this is what API level 9 maps to.  To allow your application access to TYPE_GYROSCOPE, you will have to have an Android 2.3 build on your phone.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being a nagger, but if you said there was no Gyroscope on my phone, then it wouldn't succeed - or would it? Do the links I provided give useful information about it?

Comment: Your links show me that a couple people either think they have a gyroscope or confused gyroscopes with accelerometers - it's hard to tell.  If your phone does not have a gyroscope then you won't be able to get gyroscope-based data.

Comment: Indeed, people can be easily confused (I am a living example)... Thank you very much! :)